# Self-induction and conservation of energy

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction, induction

back EMF when switch is open is greater than back EMF when it is on; is that opposes the law of conservation of energy?
[image]

Comment: What switch? In what circuit? If you include a schematic of the circuit you are asking about it will be much more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not oppose the law of the conservation of  energy. In circuits the conservation of energy is more properly represented as conservation of power. Power in a circuit is given by $P=IV$. Voltage by itself is not conserved, so a change in voltage does not indicate a failure of the conservation of energy.